# How does Serenity choose what Chromedriver to use?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd, webdrivermanager-java

I recently cloned the latest version of serenity-cucumber-starter from https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber-starter. I took the action-classes branch (as I want to use that as a starting point rather than the screenplay (master) branch) and ran mvn clean verify as instructed in the readme. I got an unusual situation wherein the webdrivermanager that comes with serenity recognised and downloaded the correct version of chromedriver based on my installed chrome but serenity proceeded to start a different version of chromedriver.

Here are the logs:

```
11:36:55.771 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  n.s.c.w.d.ChromeDriverProvider - Using automatically driver download
11:36:56.248 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Using chromedriver 107.0.5304.62 (since Chrome 107 is installed in your machine)
11:36:56.258 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as /Users/user69/.m2/repository/webdriver/chromedriver/mac64/107.0.5304.62/chromedriver
11:36:56.772 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  n.s.c.w.d.ProvideNewDriver - Instantiating driver
11:36:56.774 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  n.s.c.w.d.ProvideNewDriver - Driver capabilities: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, chrome.switches: --start-maximized;--test-ty..., goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--start-maximized, --test-type, --no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors;\n, --disable-popup-blocking, --disable-default-apps, --disable-extensions-file-a..., --incognito, --disable-infobars, --disable-gpu, --headless], extensions: []}, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging...}
Starting ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}) on port 48795
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

Of course because the wrong version of ChromeDriver starts the tests fail to run with the following:

```
Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90
Current browser version is 107.0.5304.110 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
```

After webdrivermanager correctly identifies and downloads the correct version of chromedriver how can I instruct serenity to actually use the downloaded version rather than starting some other version?

Comment: You might want to look at the serenity.conf properties options: https://serenity-bdd.github.io/docs/reference/serenity-properties

Answer (score 0):

The bonigarcia library uses the following commands to identify your installed browser version and that's the version it will automatically download.

https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/main/resources/commands.properties

You may override the driver version serenity is using with the wdm.* properties listed under the advanced configuration section here. https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#advanced-configuration

E.g. pass as environment variable when using maven "mvn clean verify -Dwdm.chromeDriverVersion=107"

But, under normal circumstances you don't need to do so, if automatic driver resolution works.